# Generate ajax object in a single line

Tags: javascript

Following my code:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

It does not work, how to solve, and then generate the appropriate ajax object in a single line? I don't want to use any framework.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: You could declare a function that returns the object. Calling the function can be done in one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var ajax = XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

Comment: In the **IE6** error will be raised, due to undefined object - *Uncaught ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined*, so instead of implicit boolean casting it would be better if you check *typeof*

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var ajax = typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"
    ? new XMLHttpRequest()
    : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```